# Doubts about Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: cloud, infrastructure

Maybe a little more of the same questions that others have asked but wanted to clarify my doubt, for some years run my hosting company (reseller of [esds](http://www.esds.co.in/)) and I've done well so far, but I am determined to bring quality and server technology to offer another level. So far I have understood that there is a difference between cloud and cluster servers because the cluster function as load balancers that distribute in different servers roles and use the servers less overloaded in the cloud is the union of multiple servers and then the same is vitualized unlike the cluster that is allowed to use the resources of the CPU and RAM servers in the virtualized environment.

My approach is to use 3 dedicated servers to create a cloud server, My doubts:

Does this type of cloud servers are only reserved for big companies? (Either because the union of the servers is done by hardware or software with high price)
What characteristics should these servers meet?
Possibly through software which should be used? Available?

Thanks for your time, 
Cheers!

Comment: serverfault does not do product recommendations. Also, I do not really understand your question. What is it what you're actually asking? You might want to read up on the topic of virtualization.

Comment: He is not asking for a product recommendation but on a more generic level. THat is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that "cloud" means nothing - it is a marketing term. Practically it is the fast purposing of servers via automated means and (most often) also accounted for by the hour. It does not HAVE to be virtualization - for some things that makes no sense (HPC clusters coming to my mind), although VERY often it means virtual machines.

The rest is blablabla.

> My approach is to use 3 dedicated servers to create a cloud server,

This would require extremely expensive hardware and a hypervisor with a large cost - one of the few capable of single system imaging. They do exist, but normally you would say you create a cloud, not a cloud server.

The cloud is really about being flexible to assign resources fast. That is all there is.

Now for software recommendations - not here dude, do your own homework. THAT SAID: the two large commercial (!) players are VmWare and Microsoft (Hyper-V), and there are a ton of smaller / non enterprise vendors around (among them XEN). What makes a cloud a cloud, though, is the dynamic management from one place.